# What's an efficient way to crawl multiple pages on a website without yielding/creating a request/method for each page using scrapy?

Tags: python, web-scraping, twisted, scrapy

Just as an example, I'm using Yelp. Yelp doesn't list emails, so if you wanted to acquire Yelp emails you would need to scrape a listing and then yield a request to that listings website and crawl it for an email. Currently, I'm crawling the homepage of the listings website, and if the email, phone number, etc. isn't listed on that page then I load the contact page and check there. The problem I'm having is that the information I'm looking for isn't always on these pages. It would be ideal to load all of the links on a website that contain certain keywords and then create a method that looks through all of these pages for the emails, phone numbers, etc and return them when found. What would be a good way to go about doing this? Here is how I'm currently crawling through the pages of a website:

```
        rules = (
            Rule(LinkExtractor(allow=r'biz', restrict_xpaths='//*[contains(@class, "natural-search-result")]//a[@class="biz-name"]'), callback='parse_item', follow=True),
            Rule(LinkExtractor(allow=r'start', restrict_xpaths='//a[contains(@class, "prev-next")]'), follow=True)
        )

        def parse_item(self, response):
            i = YelpscraperItem()
            i['phone'] = self.beautify(response.xpath('//*[@class="biz-phone"]/text()').extract())
            i['state'] = self.beautify(response.xpath('//span[@itemprop="addressRegion"]/text()').extract())
            i['company'] = self.beautify(response.xpath('//h1[contains(@class, "biz-page-title")]/text()').extract())

            website = i['website'] = self.beautify(response.xpath('//div[@class="biz-website"]/a/text()').extract())
            if type(website) is list and website:
                website = self.checkScheme(website[0])
                request = Request(website, callback=self.parse_home_page, dont_filter=True)
                request.meta['item'] = i
                yield request
            else:
                yield i

        def parse_home_page(self, response):
            try:
                i = response.meta['item']
                sel = Selector(response)
                rawEmail = sel.xpath("substring-after(//a[starts-with(@href, 'mailto:')]/@href, 'mailto:')").extract()
                if (type(rawEmail) is list) and ('@' in rawEmail[0]):
                    i = self.format_email(rawEmail, i, "Home Page (Link)")
                    yield i
                else:
                    rawContactPage = response.xpath("//a[contains(@href, 'contact')]/@href").extract()
                    if type(rawContactPage) is list and rawContactPage:
                        contactPage = rawContactPage[0]
                        contactPage = urlparse.urljoin(response.url, contactPage.strip())
                        request = Request(contactPage, callback=self.parse_contact_page, dont_filter=True)
                        request.meta['item'] = i
                        request.meta['home-page-response'] = response
                        yield request
                    else:
                        yield i
            except TypeError as er:
                print er

        def parse_contact_page(self, response):
            try:
                i = response.meta['item']
                homePageResponse = response.meta['home-page-response']
                rawEmail = response.xpath("substring-after(//a[starts-with(@href, 'mailto:')]/@href, 'mailto:')").extract()
                if (type(rawEmail) is list) and ('@' in rawEmail[0]):
                    i = self.format_email(rawEmail, i, "Contact Page (Link)")
                elif (type(rawEmail) is list) and (rawEmail[0] == ''):
                    rawEmail = response.xpath('//body').re(r'[a-zA-Z0-9\.\-+_]+@[a-zA-Z0-9\.\-+_]+\.[A-Za-z]{2,3}')
                    if (type(rawEmail) is list) and rawEmail:
                        i = self.format_email(rawEmail, i, "Contact Page (Text)")
                    else:
                        rawEmail = homePageResponse.xpath('//body').re(r'[a-zA-Z0-9\.\-+_]+@[a-zA-Z0-9\.\-+_]+\.[A-Za-z]{2,3}')
                        if (type(rawEmail) is list) and rawEmail:
                            i = self.format_email(rawEmail, i, "Home Page (Text)")
                        else:
                            rawEmail = [self.get_whois_email(i)]
                            i = self.format_email(rawEmail, i, "Whois Page")
                yield i
            except TypeError as er:
                print er

        def get_whois_email(self, i):
            email = ""
            try:
                if 'website' in i.keys():
                    website = i['website']
                    if type(website) is list:
                        website = i['website'][0].lower()
                    w = whois.whois(website)
                    for whoisEmail in w.emails:
                        whoisEmail = whoisEmail.lower()
                        if website in whoisEmail:
                            email = whoisEmail
                        else:
                            for domain in self.whiteListed:
                                    if domain in whoisEmail:
                                        email = whoisEmail
            except IndexError as er:
                log.msg("Whois Email IndexError:")
            return email
```

Answer (score 0):

That's the way Scrapy works as it's based on Twisted, an asynchronous framework. Each crawled page is handled by a single callback.

I think the only way to pass information from one callback to another is the way you're doing, via the request's meta attribute.